# C# - NET 4.0 - Cryptography: handling signing and encode/decode using SHA256 and PKCS#10

Tags: c#, cryptography, .net-4.0, sha256, pkcs#10

I'm facing a new situation involving a program, written in .NET Framework 4.0/C#, which has to encode/decode and sign messages to be sent/received in a particular kind of WAN.
This is the current scenario, which is working fine.
We have a .p12 file (which contains the sender certificate) and a .cer file (which contains the receiver certificate), which are both installed in the pc.
The scenario is working using SHA1 and PKCS#7 at 1024 bit, so the following piece of code works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections;
private static string senderCert = "sendername"; //the name registered in .p12 file
private static string receiverCert = "receivername"; //the name registered in .cer file
    /// <summary>
    ///verify that the receiving message is signed
    ///and returns the data without sign
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="signedData">dataflow with sign</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] Verify(this byte[] signedData)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certPub = GetReceiverCert(); 
        if (certPub == null) return null;

        ContentInfo decodeContentInfo = new ContentInfo(signedData);
        SignedCms decodeCMS = new SignedCms(decodeContentInfo, false);

        try
        {
            //decode the message, if it isn't signed, raise an exception
            decodeCMS.Decode(signedData);
            SignerInfo signerInfo = decodeCMS.SignerInfos[0];

            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = new 
                        X509Certificate2Collection(certPub);                
            return decodeCMS.ContentInfo.Content;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException err)
        {
            Logger.Log(err);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the certificate used to sign the sending messages
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 GetSenderCert()
    {
        //Open the personal certificates folder
        X509Store storeMy = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        storeMy.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        //find the proper certificate
        X509Certificate2Collection certColl = storeMy.Certificates.Find 
        (X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, senderCert, false);

        //Check if certificate exists in the collection, otherwise returns null             
            if (certColl.Count == 0)
            return null;
        storeMy.Close();
        return certColl[0];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the certificate used to control the sign of the receiving messages
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 GetReceiverCert()
    {
        //Open personal certificates' folder
        X509Store storeMy = new X509Store(StoreName.My,
            StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        storeMy.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        //find the certificate use for this kind of messages
        X509Certificate2Collection certColl = storeMy.Certificates.Find 
                 (X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, receiverCert, false);

        //Check if certificate exists in the collection, otherwise returns null
        if (certColl.Count == 0)
            return null;
        storeMy.Close();
        return certColl[0];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a sign to the message
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">message data flow</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] Sign(this byte[] data)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetSenderCert();
        if (certificate == null) return null;            
        if (data == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        if (certificate == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");

        //Set the message to sign
        ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(data);
        signedCms = new SignedCms(content, false);
        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);            
        signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly; 

        //Create the sign
        signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
        return signedCms.Encode();
    }
```

As I said before, this code works fine under the given scenario (SHA1+PKCS#7 at 1024 bit).
Now the client asks an update of the crypthography, in particular using **SHA256** instead of SHA1 and **PKCS#10** instead of PKCS#7 with key length 2048 bit instead of 1024.

According to your experience, what should I do to get the new requirements?

The only thing I'm sure is that I cannot use a NET Framework greater than this one because the devices are old XPs and they cannot be changed for company issues. So I cannot use new libraries released for .NET 4.7.1 to solve my problem.

I suppose that the new certificates will be released as the previous method, a file for sender, another one for receiver, to be installed in the machine.

Honestly I haven't a lot of experience with crypto and I would like to find an easy path which can follow the logic of the current methods, since the fact their scope wouldn't be changed, but just the signing approach.

I have no other limitations in using other libraries, pinvoke and other stuff, if it can really help.

Thanks to all of you for your support
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Regards

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

I had a clarification from national agency regarding what it wants.
First of all, it clarified that #PKCS10 at 2048 bit refers to the way in which the new certificate is requested. They are needed two openssl requests, with a specific paradigm, and two files are generated: a .p12 file (for sender, to sign message) released with the PKCS#10 request at 2048 bit, and another file (I suppose a .cer file) for receiver, to decode files.

For the rest they confirm the switching from SHA1 to SHA2.
I will continue to communicate with them to have further info, but on the basis of what they explained, taken into account that I will still have to install the new certificates on the computer and using them for the usual actions, is it enough to change the algorithm from SHA1 (default) to SHA2 or should I do anything else?
Thanks, Regards

Comment: SignedCms (PKCS#7/CMS) and PKCS#10 (certification signing request) have very little to do with each other.  If they're replacing one with the other that's not an "upgrade" so much as an "overhaul".

Comment: Hi @bartonjs, I agree with you regarding the differences. I just meant that the national agency just said that it wants that the messages would be signed in this way despite the previous one. I have no problems in rewriting the methods needed to sign/decode the messages, but I would like to have proper suggestons about the best paths to accomplish that. Regards

Comment: I guess what I mean is “none of the current code is relevant to your new task”, and “there’s no real path”. You’re starting over fresh. .NET doesn’t have built-in support for creating PKCS#10 until 4.7.2, so if you can’t upgrade your choices are “write it from scratch” and “find a library”. If you were writing from scratch and couldn’t get something to work, that would be on-topic (if you give the what’s wrong, what does right mean, and broken code). If you’re asking for a library that’s off topic (have you tried Bouncy Castle?).

Comment: Have a read of [PKCS#10](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2986) and you'll understand that PKCS#10 has nothing to do with "messages".

Comment: Guys, thanks for your replies. I want to emphasize that I'm not the subject which decided this change, but just one of the entities which must model the new requirements given by this national agency. By taking into account that at the moment some details are missing, the core of the new request is the following (translated from Italian): "we precise that all the certificates released by the CA XXXXXX will have the hash algorythm SHA-256 (SHA-2) instead of the obsolete SHA-1, **and key dimension of new PKCS#10 (format of certificate request) must have a length of 2048 bits**

Comment: I understand that this method seems have nothing to do with the dialog (in terms of data flow) we have to share with the "remote server", but this is what they say. So, according to your experience, do you think that now they want that each host verifies itself by asking a pkcs10 certificate and then all the messages will continue to be signed with the same current method (by changing SHA1 with SHA2)?